# Can server send multiple certificates to client?

Tags: ssl, https, client-server, ssl-certificate, tls1.2

I have written small Java 7 Client and Server application. I have keystore with 3 Self-signed X.509 RSA Certificates. When client connects through SSL, server sends SSL Certificate message with only one certificate. I am bit new to SSL/TLS. I also looked at JSSE code sun.security.ssl.X509KeyManagerImpl, and found below comments:

```
/*
 * Return the best alias that fits the given parameters.
 * The algorithm we use is:
 *   . scan through all the aliases in all builders in order
 *   . as soon as we find a perfect match, return
 *     (i.e. a match with a cert that has appropriate key usage
 *      and is not expired).
 *   . if we do not find a perfect match, keep looping and remember
 *     the imperfect matches
 *   . at the end, sort the imperfect matches. we prefer expired certs
 *     with appropriate key usage to certs with the wrong key usage.
 *     return the first one of them.
 */
private String More ...chooseAlias(List<KeyType> keyTypeList,
        Principal[] issuers, CheckType checkType)
```

Comment is pretty clear that server will send single best matching certificate but I don't seem to understand the reason. Like in my case, I want server to send all 3 certificates, so client can pick one and validate the chain. And also, if my client doesn't have the certificate that server sends, the connection is dropped with SSLHandshakeException 'No trusted certificate found'. So my question is that why can't server send all 3 certificates if the client requested information (from ClientHello) matches with all 3 certificates ? Is it something to do with TLS 1.0 vs TLS 1.2 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The TLS handshake protocol only provides for the transmission of one client end-entity certificate (this is also the case for server certificates).  *Intermediate* certificates can be transmitted, but what you seem to want - transmission of multiple end-entity certificates - is not possible.

The structure of the TLS *Server / Client Certificate* message is defined in [RFC 5246 (TLS 1.2) section 7.4.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.4.2):

```
Structure of this message:

      opaque ASN.1Cert<1..2^24-1>;

      struct {
          ASN.1Cert certificate_list<0..2^24-1>;
      } Certificate;

   certificate_list
      This is a sequence (chain) of certificates.  The sender's
      certificate MUST come first in the list.  Each following
      certificate MUST directly certify the one preceding it.  Because
      certificate validation requires that root keys be distributed
      independently, the self-signed certificate that specifies the root
      certificate authority MAY be omitted from the chain, under the
      assumption that the remote end must already possess it in order to
      validate it in any case.
```

In regards to which certificate the client selects to present, if you configure your server to advertise its trusted CAs for client certificate validation (the `certificate_authorities` field of the `CertificateRequest` message; see below), then the client-side code that selects the certificate to present ought to select a certificate that is certified by one of the advertised CAs.

```
7.4.4.  Certificate Request

   ...

   Structure of this message:

      enum {
          rsa_sign(1), dss_sign(2), rsa_fixed_dh(3), dss_fixed_dh(4),
          rsa_ephemeral_dh_RESERVED(5), dss_ephemeral_dh_RESERVED(6),
          fortezza_dms_RESERVED(20), (255)
      } ClientCertificateType;

      opaque DistinguishedName<1..2^16-1>;

      struct {
          ClientCertificateType certificate_types<1..2^8-1>;
          SignatureAndHashAlgorithm
            supported_signature_algorithms<2^16-1>;
          DistinguishedName certificate_authorities<0..2^16-1>;
      } CertificateRequest;

   ...

   certificate_authorities
      A list of the distinguished names [X501] of acceptable
      certificate_authorities, represented in DER-encoded format.  These
      distinguished names may specify a desired distinguished name for a
      root CA or for a subordinate CA; thus, this message can be used to
      describe known roots as well as a desired authorization space.  If
      the certificate_authorities list is empty, then the client MAY
      send any certificate of the appropriate ClientCertificateType,
      unless there is some external arrangement to the contrary.
```

And, from section 7.4.6:

```
  If the certificate_authorities list in the certificate request
  message was non-empty, one of the certificates in the certificate
  chain SHOULD be issued by one of the listed CAs.
```

Answer (score 0):

Bad luck, you can only send one. See RFC 2616 &ff.